# Custom project templates for gitlab.com SaaS (Gold or Silver Edition)

Tags: templates, gitlab, saas

Lots of mentions of this for the self-hosted version Gitlab Ultimate

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-project.html

EDIT: I'm using a 30 day trial of Gold edition right now. Does that differ from the fully paid edition?

However when I try to create a new projet on gitlab.com it says :-

> "There are no custom project templates set up for this GitLab instance. They are enabled from GitLab's Admin Area. Contact your GitLab instance administrator to setup custom project templates.
>
> Learn more about custom project templates"

Surely **I am** the administrator!? If I'm not the administrator, how do I get that level of access for my own projects and groups?

Do I have to create a merge request to make my custom templates available for the whole world, or can I create them just for my projects or groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to use Instance-level Custom Templates, and you're using hosted/SaaS gitlab.com, you cannot create them. For gitlab.com, the instance admins that need to create them is the Gitlab team themselves. You might be able to submit a support ticket to ask for it, but it would have to be general enough for every user of gitlab.com to share.

You should be able to create Group Templates on gitlab.com though. If you don't have a group, you can create one by going to [Your Groups](https://gitlab.com/dashboard/groups) and hitting the green button for "New Group". Then, once created you can go to the group's setting page and create a custom template (as long as you have at least a Silver level subscription or higher).

If you're using self-hosted gitlab (omnibus) you can create instance or group templates as long as you have a Premium subscription or higher.

Hope this helps.